# Use sympy to minimize the surface area of a square cuboid made up of top and bottom squares and four rectangular sides meeting at right angles

Tags: python, sympy

I want to solve this problem using sympy but I am not sure how. I know how to minimize the surface area of a cuboid using calculus but not using python.

Use sympy to minimize the surface area of a square cuboid made up of top and bottom squares and four rectangular sides meeting at right angles. Let s be the length of the square's side and h be the height.

Let s be the length of the square's side and h be the height. The square cuboid's surface area is A = 2x^2+4hs since 2s^2 is the combined area of its top and bottom squares, and 4hs is the combined area of its sides. Its volume is given by V=s^2h.

[image]

The problem is to use sympy to compute the exact value of s that minimizes the square cuboid's surface area A subject to the constraint V=1. Is there a common name for the area-minimizing solid you come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sympy doesn't seem to have a function for symbolic minimization.  One could
Here is a possible approach:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, lambdify

h, s = symbols('h s', real=True, positive=True)
# formula for the area
A = s * s + 4 * h * s
# equation for the volume which should be 1
volume = Eq(s * s * h, 1)
# h_given_s = solve(volume, h)[0]  # h_given_s = s**(-2)
# using the volume equation, express h as a function of s
# and substitute that solution into A
A_s = A.subs(h, solve(volume, h)[0])  # A = s**2 + 4/s
# find the zeros of the first derivative
ans = solve(A_s.diff(s))[0]
print(f'answer: {ans} (={ans.evalf()})')
```

answer: `2**(1/3) (=1.25992104989487)`

Another approach would involve scipy's numeric minimization:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize as scipy_min

A_np = lambdify(s, A_s)
scipy_min(A_np, 1)
```

Result: `1.25992129`